# SceneKit material blinking

Tags: swift, animation, scenekit

I want to make a node blinking (loop from input color to current firstMaterial for example). The node has a material which is shared with many others nodes but I don't want all the nodes blinking (only selected nodes).

I succeeded to do that **without** SCNAction/SCNTransaction but the code is dirty, very hard to maintain and must be called in Update()... I was wondering if SCNAction/SCNTransaction could help me but I don't know how to do this the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe something like this will point you in the right direction.

First we will create an `extension` of `SCNNode` so that we can make use of our function on any `SCNNode`:

```
//-----------------------
//MARK: SCNNode Extension
//-----------------------

extension SCNNode{

    /// Creates A Pulsing Animation On An Infinite Loop
    ///
    /// - Parameter duration: TimeInterval
    func highlightNodeWithDurarion(_ duration: TimeInterval){

        //1. Create An SCNAction Which Emmits A Red Colour Over The Passed Duration Parameter
        let highlightAction = SCNAction.customAction(duration: duration) { (node, elapsedTime) in

            let color = UIColor(red: elapsedTime/CGFloat(duration), green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            let currentMaterial = self.geometry?.firstMaterial
            currentMaterial?.emission.contents = color

        }

        //2. Create An SCNAction Which Removes The Red Emissio Colour Over The Passed Duration Parameter
        let unHighlightAction = SCNAction.customAction(duration: duration) { (node, elapsedTime) in
            let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(1) - elapsedTime/CGFloat(duration), green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            let currentMaterial = self.geometry?.firstMaterial
            currentMaterial?.emission.contents = color

        }

        //3. Create An SCNAction Sequence Which Runs The Actions
        let pulseSequence = SCNAction.sequence([highlightAction, unHighlightAction])

        //4. Set The Loop As Infinitie
        let infiniteLoop = SCNAction.repeatForever(pulseSequence)

        //5. Run The Action
        self.runAction(infiniteLoop)
    }

}
```

Lets say that we then create an `SCNNode` with an `SCNSphereGeometry` like so:

```
let blueNode = SCNNode()
let blueGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.2)
blueGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
blueNode.geometry = blueGeometry
blueNode.position = SCNVector3(1.5, 0, -1.5)
blueNode.name = "BlueNode"
augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(redNode)
```

We can then call the `highlight function` on this (or any `SCNNode`) like so:

```
blueNode.highlightNodeWithDurarion(5)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. You're right, this point me in the right direction. SCNAction is so cool ! I've made few change in this code but it works like a charm. The thing I have to do is to unshare the material of the nodes with a simple Copy().